# How to perform join with where clause on previously filtered single record integer value in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, filter, apache-spark-sql

I would like to filter a Spark Dataframe based on a previously filtered out single record. The data looks as follows:

```
val columns = Seq("language", "users_count", "time_window")
val data = Seq(("Java", "20000", "2021-04-05"),("Java", "20000", "2021-08-05"), ("Python", "100000", "2021-05-05"), ("Scala", "3000", "2021-07-05"), ("Python", "3000", "2021-03-05"))

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val dfFromRDD1 = rdd.toDF(columns: _*)

val dfFromRDD2 = dfFromRDD1.withColumn("time_window", date_format(col("time_window"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
                           .orderBy(desc("time_window")) // Note that I sorted the data based on time
```

Filter record:

```
val filterRow =
  dfFromRDD3.filter(dfFromRDD3("language") === "Python").limit(1)
```

The expected result should be as in the red box in below picture. Put in words, I would like to only keep those records which came after the most recent `Python` entry (plus entry containing `python`).

[image]

What I tried:

```
val dfFromRDD3 = dfFromRDD2.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())

val result = dfFromRDD3.as("df").join(
  filterRow.as("filterRow"),
  Seq("idx"),
  "left_outer"
).where($"df.idx" <= filterRow("idx").as[Integer])
```

Explanation: My idea was to create an index column, which can then be used to keep only the desired records.

Note:

- This could probably be done without idx column, but it is nice when joining since no joins on Strings or multiple key columns are needed
- In know filter and where are alias of each other. It just helped to explain the question to distinguish between them.
- Probably I am using the wrong join or something is messed up witht the datatypes?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
[mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have this table called `ds1`:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
|language|user_count|time_window|
+--------+----------+-----------+
|    Java|     20000| 2021-04-05|
|   Scala|      3000| 2021-07-05|
|    Java|     20000| 2021-08-05|
|  Python|    100000| 2021-05-05|
|  Python|     15000| 2021-03-03|
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Before we move on, we create an `id` and sort on `time_window` desc:

```
ds1 = ds1.withColumn("id", expr("row_number() over (order by time_window desc)"))
```

Then, we filter the language, we group by `id` and find the maximum `time_window` (we group by just to have the value in our table), and we get the `id` value of the first row (which is the maximum date):

```
val minId = ds1
  .filter(col("language") === "Python")
  .groupBy("id").agg(max(col("time_window")))
  .rdd.collect()(0)(0)
```

Finally, we filter `id`s lower than our found `id`:

```
ds1 = ds1.filter(col("id").leq(minId))
```

Final output:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+---+
|language|user_count|time_window| id|
+--------+----------+-----------+---+
|    Java|     20000| 2021-08-05|  1|
|   Scala|      3000| 2021-07-05|  2|
|  Python|    100000| 2021-05-05|  3|
+--------+----------+-----------+---+
```

Hope this helps, good luck!